# How to migrate from Oracle RDB for OpenVMS to MySQL in Windows?

Tags: mysql, migration, openvms, oracle-rdb

I have a legacy Alpha server with a [RDB](http://www3.sympatico.ca/n.rieck/docs/openvms_notes_rms_rdb.html#rdb) database. This db is replicated in a MySQL db with many bad php scripts that drops all the tables and takes everything from the Alpha.

This works very slow and is becoming unmaintainable. Is there a better way to fix this than programming again the scripts? Anything like MySQL Migration Toolkit?

Comment: This may be more applicable for serverfault as it is about RDBMS migration. Stackoverflow is mostly for programming questions and Serverfault for system administration questions. There is a logo in the footer to get there.

Comment: I searched about openvms at both sites and I founded more results here. It's a question that I think can be in both sites cause it's programming and server related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has been ported to OpenVMS/Alpha.  If you could migrate your applications to use MySQL on the Alpha, then you could use MySQL's built-in replication.

This [wiki page](http://www.vmsmysql.org/DownloadAndInstallationMySQL5122) has installation instructions and download links.

Comment: This may be a good idea but I have no experience with OpenVMS and no support from the people who has mantained this for twenty years.

Comment: @polyphony: I started in excactly the same situation with regards to MySQL on OpenVMS, no internal support, etc.  All I can say is good luck.  I added a link that will come in handy if you decide to go this route.